# jQuery .css() has it out for me

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to store the opacity of a css class into a js variable. I've searched the boards and the .css function is just not working for me. Here's the css for one class from which I'd like to pull opacity:

```
{   .a1
    height:40px;
    width:600px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Georgia;
    opacity:1;
}
```

I have several classes named similarly (...a2, a3, a4, a5). I'm trying to run a loop in jQuery to pull opacities for each of the classes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.checkme').click(function() {

    var opac = 0;
    var div = "";
    for (i=1;i<6;i++){

        div = ".a"+i.toString();
        opac = $(div).css('opacity');

        if (opac==1) {
                ...
            } 
            else if (opac==.1){
                ...
            }   
            else if (opac==.2){
                ...
            }
};
});});
```

I've tried adjusting the class the .css function pulls to various strings just to test it, but for whatever reason, it won't pull the opacity into either a numeric value *or* a string. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code seems to be missing

Comment: I prematurely clicked post. Sorry about that.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yz4zj/1/

Comment: keep in mind if have more than one of each class...`opac = $(div).css('opacity');` will only return value of the first eleemnt in the collection

Comment: Arun, shouldn't the console log "1"? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what exactly it is that .css does.

Comment: @user3051125 you need to click the the text http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yz4zj/2/ because the `css()` call is within the click handler

Comment: Arun, thank you--but I'm getting nothing.

Comment: Try this... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yz4zj/4/

Comment: @user3051125: which browser & jquery-version do you use?

Comment: I'm still getting nothing, Arun--is that code working for you on JSFiddle? Returning the opacities in the Results frame when you click the button? I'm not getting anything, and I agree the code should work. :/

...and Dr. Molle, I'm using the latest jQuery with Dreamweaver. I've tried the latest versions of ie, firefox, and chrome.

Comment: If I recall right, .css() returns a string.  You must parse it as an integer/float to use it in the way you are.